# Can't make the event "onchange" on <select> work in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

I've tried a lot of ways to make it work, never succeed.

Here is the code :

JS :

```
console.debug("before");
$("#link-ranges").onchange = function() {
    console.debug("test");
};
```

`before` is displayed once, test is never while i'm clicking on the options.

HTML :

```
<label for="link-ranges">Link target entities</label>
<div class="controls" id="rangeDiv">
    <select class="span12" id="link-ranges" size="5"></select>
</div>
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="range-list-template">
    {{#if ranges}}
        <select class="span12" id="link-ranges" size="5">
            {{#each ranges}}
                <option value="{{this.id}}">
                    {{this.name}}
                </option>
                {{rangeOption}}
            {{/each}}
        </select>
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

Here is the result in the HTML page :

```
<select class="span12" id="link-ranges" size="5">
    <option value="1">
        data1
    </option>
    <option value="2">
        data2
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Try `$('#link-ranges').on('change',function(){ ... });` instead of setting an `onchange` property on the jQuery selector.

Comment: This doesn't work surprisingly.

Answer (score 2):

That is invalid syntax for change in jquery. Also ensure that you wrap the code in DOM ready event. try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#link-ranges").on('change',function() {
      console.debug("test");
  });
});
```

Comment: As I said, I tried a lot of methods, this doesn't work for me. (you forgot to close the parenthesis)

Comment: Yes this is a huge code, I'm showing you a tiny element in which I couldn't attach an event via javascript. I wondered if handlebars didn't isn't the cause, because the select created via handlebars has the same id as the one above, but when the page is rendered, there is only one select, the one of handlebar, if there is at least one element.

Comment: @Elfayer : give it a shot by wrapping the code in dom ready. also check if any error exists in console.

Comment: Doesn't change anything, and there is no error in the console. I know it should work, that's why I ask. ^^ I don't know what to do to solve this.

Comment: @Elfayer:check id of select option after rendering.

Comment: @Elfayer :can you create the problem fiddle.

Comment: I don't think so, I asked for a miracle, because it should work, somehow it doesn't...

Answer (score -1):

```
  $( "#link-ranges").live('change',function() {
     console.debug("test");
    };
```

or

```
 $( "#link-ranges").on('change',function() {
     console.debug("test");
    };
```

Comment: Don't use `$.live`, use `$.on`.

Comment: @Bic why not please explain i don't know yet ?

Comment: @MsiSaurovh The [`.live()`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7.

Comment: Yep : `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'`